# I can't share data from request with JSON and Volley to other android activity

Tags: android, callback, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I am making a request with JsonObjectRequest and Volley in a java class and, once I get the data, I can't send it to the activity where I need to use it. I tried using a callback but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I've tried several things but none of them worked. I get the data correctly in my request class so the problem is to get that data from the activity.

I think my problem is related with the callback but, as I said, I've tried everything I could.

Any help would be appreciated!

- This is my request code:

  ```
  public ArrayList<Coin> getMarketSummary(final DashboardActivity.CoinCallback callback, ArrayList<Coin> listAux, Context context) {

  Log.d("chegamos a entrar en getCOinData??", "Entramos en getMarketSummary");

  listCoins.clear();

  requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

  for (Coin coinAux : listAux) {
      this.coin = coinAux;

      if (!coin.getShortName().equals("BTC")) {
          //we create the URL for request the market
          String urlMarket = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-SHORTNAME";

          String coinShortName = coin.getShortName();

          urlMarket = urlMarket.replaceAll("SHORTNAME", coinShortName.toLowerCase());

          //once created the url, we create the request with JSONObject

          JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlMarket, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                  try {

                      JSONArray result = response.getJSONArray("result");
                      //we loop the response
                      for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                          coin.setHigh(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("High")));

                          coin.setLow(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Low")));
                          coin.setLast(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Last")));
                          coin.setVolInBtc(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("BaseVolume")));
                          coin.setBid(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Bid")));
                          coin.setAsk(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Ask")));
                          coin.setPrevDay(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("PrevDay"));

                          listCoins.add(coin);
                          callback.onSuccess(listCoins);

                      }
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }

              }
          }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
              @Override
              public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                  error.printStackTrace();
              }
          });

          requestQueue.add(request);
      }
  }

  return listCoins;
  }
  ```
- This is how I initialize the callback (before making the request):

  ```
  public void initCallback() {

  this.coinCallback = new CoinCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Coin> coinListFromRequest) {
          coinList=coinListFromRequest;
      }
  };
  }
  ```
- Here is how I call the request (after I initialize the callback):

  ```
  coinList = bittrexAPIRequest.getMarketSummary(coinCallback, coinList, this);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  ```
- For last, my CoinCallback interface:

  ```
  public interface CoinCallback {
  void onSuccess(ArrayList<Coin> coinList);

  }
  ```

Comment: why are you calling the service request inside the callback again? will that be an infinite loop?

Comment: @Emil , I've just changed it in my code and edited my question. Is that what you mean? I've tested the change in my code and it is still not working. NOTE: "coinList" is a private variable for my activity

Comment: ya. thats what i meant. Now I suppose you are using this data (coinList) to show in a listview. right? And you are trying to update the listview by calling adapter.notifydatasetchanged. right?

Comment: @Emil Yes, I use "coinList" in my adapter to show the data in a listView. The listView updates the rows in the list but not its content. For example, If i add a new row with a new name, the new name is shown but not its value

Comment: ok. ``coinList=coinListFromRequest;`` don't do this. instead ``coinList.addAll(coinListFromRequest);`` because if you assign a new reference to the list object which is originally used with the adapter, the notifyDatsetchanged method wont work properly. do this in the callback and call ``adapter.notifydatasetchanged()``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is mistake getMarketSummary() always return Empty list.so made getMarketSummary return type void and pass the list in  CoinCallback interface.

```
  public void getMarketSummary(final DashboardActivity.CoinCallback callback, ArrayList<Coin> listAux, Context context) {

        Log.d("chegamos a entrar en getCOinData??", "Entramos en getMarketSummary");

        listCoins.clear();

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        for (Coin coinAux : listAux) {
            this.coin = coinAux;

            if (!coin.getShortName().equals("BTC")) {
                //we create the URL for request the market
                String urlMarket = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-SHORTNAME";

                String coinShortName = coin.getShortName();

                urlMarket = urlMarket.replaceAll("SHORTNAME", coinShortName.toLowerCase());

                //once created the url, we create the request with JSONObject

                JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlMarket, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {

                            JSONArray result = response.getJSONArray("result");
                            //we loop the response
                            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                                coin.setHigh(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("High")));

                                coin.setLow(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Low")));
                                coin.setLast(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Last")));
                                coin.setVolInBtc(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("BaseVolume")));
                                coin.setBid(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Bid")));
                                coin.setAsk(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Ask")));
                                coin.setPrevDay(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("PrevDay"));

                                listCoins.add(coin);


                            }
                           callback.onSuccess(listCoins);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

                requestQueue.add(request);
            }
        }

        //return listCoins;
        }
```

update the `iniCallBack`, now updated list be return in `onSuccess` also you have call the server in `for` it may call the same service multiple time.

```
  public void initCallback() {
    coinList =new ArrayList();
    adapter =new Adapter(coinList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    this.coinCallback = new CoinCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Coin> coinList) {
           coinList.addAll(coinList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    bittrexAPIRequest.getMarketSummary(coinCallback, coinList, this);
    }
```